# Doctrine 2, 1:M bidirectional persist doesn't work properly

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, associations, persist

I am trying to persist in to Owning side using doctrine 2 in a 1:M bidirectional association. For some strange reason (at least for me its strange), I do not get the `accountId` value in to the Insert Statement and due to that reason it fails. I am not sure if I am doing anything wrong here.

Can anybody point out whats happening.

** using Zend Framework 2 + ubuntu + mysql.

table tAccounts key is `accountId` and this table being connected via foreign key `accountId` to tAccountPasswordReset

(Owning side).

```
class tAccountPasswordReset {
/**
* @ORM\Id
* @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
* @ORM\Column(type="integer")
*/
protected $Id;
/** @ORM\Column(type="integer") */
protected $accountId;
.......
.......
/** 
* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="tAccounts", inversedBy="accountpasswordreset")
* @ORM\JoinColumn(name="accountId", referencedColumnName="accountId")
**/
private $accounts;
```

(Inverse Side)

```
class tAccounts {
/**
* @ORM\Id
* @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
* @ORM\Column(type="integer")
*/
protected $accountId;
/** @ORM\Column(type="string") */
```

....
   ....

```
/** @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="tAccountPasswordReset", mappedBy="accounts") */
private $accountpasswordreset;

public function __construct() {
    /** Get the dependence rowset from the tAccountPasswordReset */
    $this->accountpasswordreset = new ArrayCollection();
}
```

Inserting a row in to tAccountPaswordReset 
(**I am positive about accountId not being null**)

```
private function setResetToken($accountid) {
    try {
        $token = uniqid().uniqid(); /** Generate a unique token */
        $newReset = new \Entity\Tables\tAccountPasswordReset();
        $newReset->accountId = $accountid;
        $newReset->resetToken = $token;
        $this->entityManager->persist($newReset);
        $this->entityManager->flush();
        return $token;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        throw $e;
    }
}
```

(Results)

```
An exception occurred while executing '
INSERT INTO tAccountPasswordReset (accountId, resetToken, createTime, expTime) 
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)' with params [null, "5273f94bd75f15273f94bd7641", "2013-11-01 14:56:11", "2013-11-02 14:56:11"]: SQLSTATE[23000]: 
Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'accountId' cannot be null
```

Answer (score 0):

From this it looks simple that you are not setting an Object of **AccountID** type to **tAccountPasswordReset**,

means you need to set or explicitly pass **tAccounts** object to **tAccountPasswordReset**'s function which is doing something similar to setter/getter.

I would suggest you do something like this in **tAccountPasswordReset** Class

```
public function getTAccount(){
 return $this->AccountID;
 } 

 public function setTAccount((complete path to this class)/tAccounts $tAccounts){
 $this->AccountID = $tAccounts;
}
```

And then in your **setResetToken** function, set tAccounts object to setter like this

```
  $newReset->setTAccount(pass tAccounts object here);// if you dont know how to set object here comment below
```

And rest of the work will be handled by Doctrine.

PS: At the moment it dont look Bi-Directional to me for now, but if it is do mention it so i may understand it.

Comment: [tAccountPasswordReset](https://gist.github.com/ppeiris/7282681) and [tAccounts](https://gist.github.com/ppeiris/7282690) and [calling function](https://gist.github.com/ppeiris/7282759). Now it try to add a record in to the tAccounts table when I try to add a record in to tAccountPasswordReset table. May be in this case I do not need to define 1:M bidirectional relationship. I may just need 1:M unidirectional. In that case I may be misunderstood the different between uni/bidirectional associations in Doctrine.

Comment: Let be be clear about that I am trying to do here. I just need to add a record in to tAccountPasswordReset table which is link with the tAccounts table via accountId (accountId is the primary key in the tAccounts table and FK in the tAccountPasswordReset  table).

Comment: i already got what u want, but you need to understand this , if you want to do what you said in pervious comment , then you need to pass Taccount Object to tAccountPasswordReset